# HTTPS request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, https, openshift

I am trying to write a NodeJS app which will talk to the OpenShift REST API using the request method in the https package. Here is the code:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'openshift.redhat.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/broker/rest/api',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

But this is giving me an error (status code 500 is returned). When I did the same thing using curl on the command line,

```
curl -k -X GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
```

I am getting the correct response from the server.

Is there anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Comparing what headers curl and node sent, i found that adding:

```
headers: {
    accept: '*/*'
}
```

to `options` fixed it.

---

To see which headers curl sends, you can use the `-v` argument.
`curl -vIX GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api`

In node, just `console.log(req._headers)` after `req.end()`.

---

*Quick tip: You can use `https.get()`, instead of `https.request()`. It will set method to `GET`, and calls `req.end()` for you.*