# HTTPS request with query strings in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, https, query-string

I am trying to make a request to an API using the `get` method in the https module.

Looking at [HTTPS request in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851858/https-request-in-nodejs), I've got a long way, but my request doesn't appear to include the query parameters…

Using the example from above, with my mods:

```
var $q = require('q'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    path = require('path'),
    Qs = require('qs'),
    path = require('path'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    https = require('https');

var params = {
  schema: '1.0',
  form: 'json',
  username: 'name'
}
var options = {
  host: 'openshift.redhat.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/broker/rest/api',
  query: params
};

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback there is no option called "query". You need to include the query parameters to the "path".

> Request path. Defaults to '/'. Should include query string if any. E.G. '/index.html?page=12'.

Comment: That's great! Don't know where I got that `query` option… 

Apparently I can't accept your answer yet, but I will! Thank you

Comment: You could also use https://github.com/ljharb/qs to easily serialize an object to a query string and not have to do that string hacking manually.

Comment: We are actually using qs, so from the example above, I have: `+ path: '/broker/rest/api' + Qs.stringify(params)`.